# Does Java Trove4J library (or another) have boolean primitive collections?

Tags: java, trove4j

Google is failing me here... I thought this would be a very simple Q&A, but I cannot find any previous discussion of the matter.

Is there a reason why the Java Trove4J library does not include boolean primitive collections?  Example: `TByteHashSet` exists, but `TBooleanHashSet` does not.

As a workaround, I can declare two byte constants for true(1) and false(0), but it would be more convenient to have a boolean primitive collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) has `BooleanSet`, `BooleanList`, `BooleanStack`, `BooleanBag` and primitive maps with boolean as values.  There are both Mutable and Immutable versions.  You can find all subinterfaces of `BooleanIterable` [here](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/BooleanIterable.html).  Factory classes for the different primitive containers are [here](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/factory/primitive/package-summary.html).

Here's an example of creating a `MutableBooleanList` and `ImmutableBooleanList` using the BooleanLists factory.

```
MutableBooleanList mutable = BooleanLists.mutable.with(true, false, true, false);
ImmutableBooleanList immutable = BooleanLists.immutable.with(true, false, true, false);
Assert.assertEquals(mutable, immutable);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author, so...

What would be your use case for such a *TBooleanHashSet*? You could only store four states:

- empty
- true
- false
- true & false

You could accomplish this easily with an EnumMap and some enum representing your states. Otherwise, the most efficient way would probably be a bit mask.

Anyway, haven't seen a need. (Note: a *TBooleanList* could make sense, but you could use *java.util.BitSet* instead.)

If you have a need, please let me know.

Comment: FYI: Goldman Sachs Collections has primitive boolean collections.  Ref: http://www.goldmansachs.com/gs-collections/javadoc/4.0.0/com/gs/collections/api/set/primitive/MutableBooleanSet.html

Comment: `empty, true, false, true & false` - in addition to _not set_ / _null_ / _none_ - took me a sec.

Comment: Reading back on my old post, I'm not sure if I was trying to be that clever or if it was just a typo. Write now I'm leaning toward typo. :-) I'll fix the states...